# Looping a block of code for certain variables in a dataset

Tags: r, loops

I have the following example data set

```
>print(data)

ID   Plant   Infloresence   displaySize   visitationRate
 1     1           1             4             0.25
 2     1           2             4             0.25
 3     1           3             4             0.25
 4     1           4             4             0.25
 5     2           1             2             1.00
 6     2           2             2             1.00
 7     3           1             1             2.00
 8     4           1             5             0.80
 9     4           2             5             0.80
10     4           3             5             0.80
11     4           4             5             0.80
12     4           5             5             0.80
13     5           1             3             0.33
14     5           2             3             0.33
15     5           3             3             0.33
```

I am leaving a lot of unneeded information out, but basically what this data set has in it is a given plant (`Plant` = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), the number of flowers on that plant (`Infloresence` = 1-4, 1-2, 1, 1-5, 1-3 respectively), and the visitation rate (calculated by dividing the number of insect visits (not shown) by the number of flowers (`displaySize`). I also have values in a separate sheet showing how much pollen insects carry on average, and we combine those averages with the shown data sheet to calculate how much pollen (as a % of 100) each insect visitor moves between plants.

When we do this, we normally care about the species as a whole and use all 300-700 rows of data at once. What I would like to do, however, is calculate this per plant (so `ID` 1-4, 5-6, 7, 8-12, and 13-15). I have the code to do it, but I don't know how to loop it so that it runs it for Plant 1, Plant 2, Plant 3, Plant 4, etc.

I don't know if that is enough information or not, I can try to be more clear if I need to be. Below is my code-- it has been tested multiple times against hand calculations and it works perfectly.

```
visitData = read.csv("caVisitation.csv", header = TRUE)     #Type the name of your formatted visitation data file between the ""
loadData = read.csv("caLoad.csv", header = TRUE)     #Type the name of your formatted pollen load data file between the ""
    pollinatorNumbers = table(unlist(visitData[, grep('Visitor', names(visitData))]))
    zeros = sum(apply(visitData[9], 2, function(x) length(which(x == 0.00000000))))
    counts = as.matrix(c(pollinatorNumbers, zeros))
    totalCounts = sum(counts[,1])
    average = mean(visitData[,9]) #This 7 indicates that the Visits/Infl/20min column is the seventh colum from the left of the page.
    percentVisits = (counts/totalCounts) 
    rate = percentVisits[-length(percentVisits),]/average
ploadData = as.data.frame(loadData, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.rm = FALSE)
ploadData$Load = as.numeric(ploadData$load)
pollenLoads  = (aggregate(load~pollinator, ploadData, FUN=mean, na.action=NULL))
pollenFlow = as.matrix((rate*pollenLoads[,2]))
    loadTotal = sum(pollenFlow[,1], na.rm = TRUE)
    percentpollenFlow = ((pollenFlow/loadTotal)*100)
        colnames(percentpollenFlow) <- c("Percent Pollen Flow")
percentpollenFlow #Returns the result in % out of 100
```

I would like to mention that I have tried to make this work, but my application of looping knowledge is rubbish.

Comment: you can do this simply via the `plyr`, `dplyr`, or `data.table` packages instead of writing custom code. This is commonly known as [split-apply-combine](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [data.tables](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table)  package.

```
 cols <- c("col_1", "col_2")
 some_data[, cols := lapply(.SD, function(x) {
           # your function code
      }, .SDcols = c("col_3", "col_4"), by = plant]
```

but it would be helpful if you post your data as well as your expected output. The `by` clause will perform the loop.

Just a remark, I would use `<-` instead of `=` when you are assigning objects to variable names.